# Sending special characters and new lines via KANNEL

Tags: bash, mobile, telephony, sms

How can I send a message to [kannel](http://www.kannel.org/overview.shtml) with lines and special character.
Example if I have file message.txt which have following text

```
line1 with few special characters like @ " / :
line 2 spaces words etc
line 3 "special characters like @ " / :
line 4 end
```

How can I pass this to KANNEL via bash using CURL ? 
like curl 
root@radius:/temp# cat test

```
#!/bin/bash
MSG=`cat /temp/message.txt`
curl "http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=kannel&password=kannelpassword&to=03333333333&text=$MSG"
```

But it says `"curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL"`

I could have used [GAMMU](http://wammu.eu/gammu/) but it is not detecting my (teltonika g/10 com serial modem, while
on kannel the modem is working fine.

Are there any other suggestions on how to send SMS via using serial modem with the text shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`--data-urlencode`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) with [`-G`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G).

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=kannel&password=kannelpassword&to=03333333333" -G --data-urlencode text@/temp/message.txt
```

You can feed the data from stdin:

```
ls -l | curl "http://127.0.0.1:13013/..." -G --data-urlencode text@-
```

Or specify it directly on the command line:

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:13013/..." -G --data-urlencode text='!@#$%^&*()'
```

Comment: one more thing . What if I want to send such messages (with spaces and special characters) via URL directly? means the message i want to send is not in text file, i wan to submit it directly via curl ?

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib Answer updated.